# Android WebRTC application. Connection outside of the network

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm compiling this two libs in order to create WebRTC android app

```
io.pristine:libjingle:9636@aar
com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.4.2
```

Whenever User-A and User-B are in the same network everything is working perfectly; once I connect one of the device to the cellular internet (4g) its not working, I'm not able to establish connection between two users. 
I'm stuck with this for week and more and I read lots of forums. As many of them suggest using STUN or TURN server. Can anyone guide me how can I create that kind of server and how I can connect Android app with this server. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In webRTC we have to use STUN and TURN servers to connect two device.Basicaly these servers are used to provide ports to client. Using these ports we can start the initial process in webRTC for connecting.
 You have to use at least 10 Servers with ratio of 9 STUN and 1 TURN. for STUN server you can check below List:
[StunServer List](http://code.google.com/p/natvpn/source/browse/trunk/stun_server_list)
A list of available STUN server:

```
stun.l.google.com:19302 

stun1.l.google.com:19302

stun2.l.google.com:19302

stun3.l.google.com:19302

stun4.l.google.com:19302

stun01.sipphone.com

stun.ekiga.net

stun.fwdnet.net

stun.ideasip.com

stun.iptel.org

stun.rixtelecom.se

stun.schlund.de

stunserver.org

stun.softjoys.com

stun.voiparound.com

stun.voipbuster.com

stun.voipstunt.com

stun.voxgratia.org

stun.xten.com
```

For TURN i recommend setup your own TURN server so that if all STUN failed at least your TURN server is their to provide port to clients.